# NSNetServices persists after stop method call?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsnetservice

I am doing a simple bonjour broadcast using NSNetServices.  Everything is working great when I start and stop the bonjour sharing at application launch/quit.  However if I turn off bonjour using the stop method call, my app still appears to be broadcasting a dead service even after the netServiceDidStop: delegate message gets called, which prevents restarting of the service until after a relaunch of the app.  Apple's documentation makes it look very straightforward, just publish or stop as needed...  Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you know that it's still broadcasting?

Comment: I am using a bonjour network browser, found here:  http://www.tildesoft.com/  It updates more or less in real time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sometimes services are shown even when they are no longer available.

From Apple documentation:

> Because failing to show a valid service is a bigger problem for the user than showing a stale service, Bonjour deliberately errs on the side of assuming that a service is still available.
>
> .
>
> .
>
> although Bonjour generally discovers new services within a few
>   seconds, if a service goes away, the disappearance of the service may
>   not be discovered until your app tries to connect to it and gets no
>   response.
>
> You should not assume that just because the Bonjour APIs report a
>   discovered service, the service is guaranteed to be available when the
>   software tries to access it.

[Connecting to and Monitoring Network Services: When resolving fails](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/ResolvingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001078-SW5)